# What does "wage an all-or-nothing return" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I use this link but don't think it helps: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wage_2

Binaries are a financial instrument where traders wage an all-or-nothing return. In this article, we’ll walk you through the top binary options brokers.

Source: https://financesonline.com/15-popular-binary-options-brokers-one-best/

Comment: It is bad writing. They do not "wage a return". They wager on an all-or-nothing return.  They bet on a win or lose proposition.

Comment: Sorry, it should be "wage an all-or-nothing return", not "wage on...".

Comment: No, the author should have written *wager on an all-or-nothing return* or *wage a bet on an all-or-nothing return*.

Comment: So you mean they may win a lot of money or nothing?

Comment: Yes, "all or nothing" is binary. There are not degrees of success. Rather, the investment succeeds or it fails.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Your comments could be a nice answer.